# Camel ActiveMQComponent when using other than openwire protocols

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, apache-camel, stomp

Following the guidelines on activemq.apache.org it's fairly easy to get up and running using openwire as transport protocol.

Letting the URI have the `trace` option, lets you see the handshaking and all: `@testing.activeMqInstance=failover:tcp://localhost:61616?trace=true`

```
09:36:06.764 [ActiveMQ Task-1] DEBUG o.a.a.t.failover.FailoverTransport - Attempting  0th  connect to: tcp://localhost:61616?trace=true
09:36:06.780 [ActiveMQ Task-1] DEBUG o.a.a.transport.WireFormatNegotiator - Sending: WireFormatInfo { version=9, properties={MaxFrameSize=9223372036854775807, CacheSize=1024, CacheEnabled=true, SizePrefixDisabled=false, MaxInactivityDurationInitalDelay=10000, TcpNoDelayEnabled=true, MaxInactivityDuration=30000, TightEncodingEnabled=true, StackTraceEnabled=true}, magic=[A,c,t,i,v,e,M,Q]}
09:36:06.780 [ActiveMQ Task-1] DEBUG o.a.a.t.TransportLogger.Connection:2 - SENDING: WireFormatInfo { version=9, properties={MaxFrameSize=9223372036854775807, CacheSize=1024, CacheEnabled=true, SizePrefixDisabled=false, MaxInactivityDurationInitalDelay=10000, TcpNoDelayEnabled=true, MaxInactivityDuration=30000, TightEncodingEnabled=true, StackTraceEnabled=true}, magic=[A,c,t,i,v,e,M,Q]}
09:36:06.780 [ActiveMQ Task-1] DEBUG o.a.a.t.failover.FailoverTransport - Connection established
09:36:06.780 [ActiveMQ Task-1] INFO  o.a.a.t.failover.FailoverTransport - Successfully connected to tcp://localhost:61616?trace=true
09:36:06.780 [ActiveMQ Transport: tcp://localhost/127.0.0.1:61616@4060] DEBUG o.a.a.t.TransportLogger.Connection:2 - RECEIVED: WireFormatInfo { version=9, properties={CacheSize=1024, MaxFrameSize=9223372036854775807, CacheEnabled=true, SizePrefixDisabled=false, TcpNoDelayEnabled=true, MaxInactivityDurationInitalDelay=10000, MaxInactivityDuration=30000, TightEncodingEnabled=true, StackTraceEnabled=true}, magic=[A,c,t,i,v,e,M,Q]}
```

However, when doing stomp (or any amqp for that matter).

Changing the URI to `@testing.activeMqInstance=failover:stomp://localhost:61612?trace=true` just seems to establish the connection (socket), and not start the protocol:

```
09:37:07.444 [ActiveMQ Task-1] DEBUG o.a.a.t.failover.FailoverTransport - urlList connectionList:[stomp://localhost:61612?trace=true], from: [stomp://localhost:61612?trace=true]
09:37:07.444 [ActiveMQ Task-1] DEBUG o.a.a.t.failover.FailoverTransport - Attempting  0th  connect to: stomp://localhost:61612?trace=true
09:37:07.444 [ActiveMQ Task-1] DEBUG o.a.a.t.failover.FailoverTransport - Connection established
09:37:07.444 [ActiveMQ Task-1] INFO  o.a.a.t.failover.FailoverTransport - Successfully connected to stomp://localhost:61612?trace=true
[silence]
```

Anybody have any insight into why there's no activity on the transport?
Got the same `trace` option on in the broker, but no `TRACE` logging occurs telling me that the client (ActiveMQComponent) doesn't event send the first `CONNECT` frame.

For reference, the component is configured using Spring xml:

```
<bean id="jmsActiveMqConnectionFactory" 
    class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="${activeMqInstance}" />
    <property name="userName" value="${activeMqUsername}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${activeMqPassword}"/>
</bean> 
<bean id="pooledActiveMqConnectionFactory" 
    class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
    property name="maxConnections" value="8" />
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsActiveMqConnectionFactory" />
</bean>
<bean id="jmsActiveMqConfig" 
    class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="pooledActiveMqConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="1"/>
</bean>
<bean id="activemq" 
    class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
    <property name="configuration" ref="jmsActiveMqConfig"/>
```

Any input is appreciated! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ActiveMQ JMS client only supports the Openwire protocol.

If you want to use STOMP, I'd recommend the stompjms client from 
https://github.com/fusesource/stompjms

If you want to use AMQP, use the AMQP 1.0 JMS client from the [Apache Qpid project](http://qpid.apache.org/)

Comment: Hi Hiram! 

I've tried to use stompjms client (1.13) - but it doesn't seem to connect properly as a durable subscriber.
The 1.12 version did, but there were some NPEs on reception of messages from the broker (retrieval of "JMSDestinationID" from the header or similar)

Comment: FYI: The client visists this code successfully before sending:

    if (persistent) {
        headerMap.put(PERSISTENT, TRUE);
    }

Comment: By the way; tried the amqp option, which resulted in this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PROTON-244 :-/

Comment: jhberges, try using a new stompjms snapshot. It's been updated to support durable subs on ActiveMQ.  It even has a tests case to verify it's working.  See: http://is.gd/xTyJce